# Websphere 8.5: Class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger does not implement Log

Tags: jsf-2, websphere, apache-commons-logging, icefaces-3, websphere-8

I developed an JSF-App with ICEFaces 3.0.1. With Tomcat and Glassfish, the App works fine. Now I wanted to test it on a WebSphere Application Server 8.5.0.0. The App starts but when I do some action, it crashes.

I'm using the following libs:

```
antlr-2.7.6.jar
commons-collections-3.1.jar
commons-lang-2.5.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
icefaces-ace.jar
icefaces-compat.jar
icefaces.jar
icepush.jar
iText-5.0.4.jar
jxl.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
hibernate3.jar
javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar
poi-3.8-20120326.jar
xpp3-1.1.4c.jar
slf4j-simple-1.7.2.jar
ojdbc6.jar
commons-logging-1.1.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
javax.faces.jar
jta-1.1.jar
```

stacktrace:

```
[11/22/12 18:57:38:284 CET] 00000063 ExtendedExcep W   queued exception
                                 javax.faces.FacesException: invalid property: md
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:84)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1214)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1027)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3703)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:962)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:522)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:311)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1783)
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: invalid property: md
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.util.PathNavigation.navigateAndReturn(PathNavigation.java:105)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.util.PathNavigation.navigate(PathNavigation.java:117)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.ClassValidator.validateValueImpl(ClassValidator.java:718)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.ClassValidator.validateValue(ClassValidator.java:239)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.ClassValidator.validateValue(ClassValidator.java:231)
    at javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.validate(BeanValidator.java:306)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validateValue(UIInput.java:1149)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:967)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1233)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:698)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.paneltabset.PanelTabSet.applyPhase(PanelTabSet.java:155)
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.paneltabset.PanelTabSet.applyPhase(PanelTabSet.java:127)
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.paneltabset.PanelTabSet.processValidators(PanelTabSet.java:199)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1172)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger does not implement Log
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:532)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:272)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:246)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:395)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtilsBean.<init>(ConvertUtilsBean.java:157)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.<init>(BeanUtilsBean.java:117)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean$1.initialValue(BeanUtilsBean.java:68)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.ContextClassLoaderLocal.get(ContextClassLoaderLocal.java:153)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.getInstance(BeanUtilsBean.java:80)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getInstance(PropertyUtilsBean.java:114)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getPropertyDescriptors(PropertyUtils.java:480)
    at org.apache.bval.util.PropertyAccess.getPropertyReadMethod(PropertyAccess.java:126)
    at org.apache.bval.util.PropertyAccess.getTypeInner(PropertyAccess.java:113)
    at org.apache.bval.util.PropertyAccess.isKnown(PropertyAccess.java:101)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.util.ValidationContextTraversal.handleProperty(ValidationContextTraversal.java:130)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.util.PathNavigation$PathPosition.handleProperty(PathNavigation.java:278)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.util.PathNavigation.parse(PathNavigation.java:143)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.util.PathNavigation.navigateAndReturn(PathNavigation.java:101)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger does not implement Log
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:416)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:525)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger does not implement Log
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:412)
    ... 64 more
```

Who can I fix this?

Comment: WebSphere comes with its own commons-logging jars. You've probably set parent-last class loading policy and now these 2 implementations collide. Removing commons-logging-1.1.jar should solve the issue. jta-1.1.jar is going to cause similar problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must delete commons-logging-1.1.jar, or when you use maven, you must set this dependency to scope "provided".