# Class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger does not implement Log

Tags: websphere, apache-commons-logging

I'm hitting the same problem described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518193/websphere-8-5-class-org-apache-commons-logging-impl-jdk14logger-does-not-implem), but I don't know my websphere version at the time

More questions 
1) does Removing commons-logging-1.1.jar fix it?
2) what if I really need to put commons-logging-1.1.jar in my application?  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the class `org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger` is loaded by a different classloader than the one that loaded the `Log` interface.

According to IBM's documentation, whenever you use a third-party library that WebSphere itself uses for its own internal purposes, you must:

1. Set your EAR's classloader policy to `PARENT_LAST`; and
2. Ensure that your EAR is self-sufficient. That is, that your third-party libraries (and their dependencies) are bundled within the EAR.

In your case:

1. Set your EAR's classloader policy to `PARENT_LAST`
2. Include `commons-logging-1.1.jar` within your EAR (you can place it in the "EAR Library" directory, usually `EAR/lib`).

Answer (score 1):

Theres a fix pack of ibm for this.
https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21502693